# Sass working but doesn't reflect on browser

Tags: html, css, sass

I have used the correct link to html file, installed Sass using npm. checked version and scss file gets correctecly mapped on CSS as well but doesn't show any changes on browser. I'm using Firefox`

index.html

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>bracu Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>`
```

scss file

```
    $primary: #FF6347;

body{
    backround:$primary;
}
```

css file

```
     body {
      backround: #FF6347;
    }
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

Comment: You've put `backround` not `background`.

Comment: Voting to close: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @stealth225 did you get your problem solved?

Comment: yes...very stupid mistake indeed